# How to apply WorksheetFunction.Average to a dynamic array in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, range, average, worksheet-function

I'm having trouble applying WorksheetFunction.Average to a dynamic array in VBA. The elements of the array are ranges and I want to be able to compute the average over the entire range of ranges in the dynamic array. I hope that makes sense. (i.e. =average(D14:F15,E17:G17) in the regular formula bar). I did a good amount of research and could not find any answers to my question.

```
With sht2.Range("B:B") 'week ending column
            Set begin_upc = .Find(upc, LookIn:=xlValues) 'find the first occurence of the upc
            Set end_upc = .Find(upc, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)   'find the last occurence of the upc
            upcRange = "A" & Range(begin_upc.Address).Row & ":" & "A" & Range(end_upc.Address).Row 'range for UPCs
            With sht2.Range(upcRange)
                For r = LBound(starts) To UBound(starts)
                    Set begin_date = .Find(starts(r), LookIn:=xlValues) 'starts is an array of start dates for the .find within the UPC range
                    Set end_date = .Find(stops(r), LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious) 'stops is an array for the .find within the UPC range
                    rangeToAvg = "O" & Range(begin_date.Address).Row & ":" & "O" & Range(end_date.Address).Row 'format the range
                    ReDim Preserve rangesForAvg(r) 'resize the array
                    rangesForAvg(r) = rangeToAvg 'append the range
                Next r
                avg_during = WorksheetFunction.Average(sht2.Range(rangesForAvg)) 'this is the line I need help with
```

Comment: When you step through the code (F8) and watch your range build, does it have the values that you expect it to have?

Comment: I'm not sure how to use F8 but when I add the line For r = LBound(rangesForAvg) To UBound(rangesForAvg) \n Debug.Print rangesForAvg(r) \n Next r after the for loop, all the right values are in the array.

Comment: When you are in the VBE click view/locals to turn on your locals window... it shows the value of each variable as it is during that step of the code. Then put your cursor at the top of your code and press F8 to start going through line by line. ... it is like the debug.print but you don't need to put it in. You can also hover your cursor over variables to see what they are at the time if they aren't arrays, ranges, etc.

Comment: Are you getting an error in your code, if so, what line is highlighted when it occurs and what error?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Rodger, all of the expressions seem to be behaving as expected. However, none of my arrays display any values. However, when I use ' r = LBound(rangesForAvg) To UBound(rangesForAvg) Debug.Print rangesForAvg(r) Next r' I do get expected values.

Comment: I am not getting any errors, @Rodger

Comment: Ok, what are the values that you are getting from the array? Just the first few.

Comment: @Rodger Sorry for the delay. It would be values such as L4:L10, L18:L28, L31:L34. The goal would be to find the average for all ranges in rangesForAvg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Dim upcRange As Range, rngData As Range, rng As Range

With sht2.Range("B:B") 'week ending column

    Set begin_upc = .Find(upc, LookIn:=xlValues)
    Set end_upc = .Find(upc, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)

    Set upcRange = sht2.Range(begin_upc, end_upc).Offset(0, -1) 'range for UPCs

    With upcRange

        Set rngData = Nothing

        For r = LBound(starts) To UBound(starts)

            Set begin_date = .Find(starts(r), LookIn:=xlValues)
            Set end_date = .Find(stops(r), LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
            Set rng = sht2.Range("O" & begin_date.Row & ":O" & end_date.Row)

            If rngData Is Nothing Then
                Set rngData = rng
            Else
                Set rngData = Application.Union(rngData, rng)
            End If

        Next r

        avg_during = WorksheetFunction.Average(rngData)
```

Comment: Thank you @Tim. It works like a charm. Thank you for also adding the checks and showing the use of application.union.